# react shallow render test, the result of renderer.getRenderOutput() not equal

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I use `react-test-renderer/shallow` to test my react component.

But the result of renderer.getRenderOutput() not equal as expected.

here is my react JSX:

```
 return (
      <div onClick={() => this.onClick('react is awesome')} className="root">
        <input type="text" onChange={this.onInputChange} value={this.state.value} />
      </div>
    );
```

and this is my test:

```
 it('renders correctly', () => {
      renderer.render(<Component />);
      instance = renderer.getRenderOutput();

      expect(instance.type).toBe('div');
      expect(instance.props.className).toBe('root');
      expect(instance.props.children.type).toBe('input');
      console.log(instance.props.children);

      expect(instance.props.children).toEqual( <input type="text" value="" />);

    });
```

the test result:

```
Expected value to equal:
      <input type="text" value="" />
    Received:
      <input onChange={[Function anonymous]} type="text" value="" />

    Difference:

    - Expected
    + Received

     <input
    +  onChange={[Function anonymous]}
       type="text"
       value=""
     />
```

As you can see, the received value has a `onChange={[Function anonymous]}`.

What should I do to let this test pass?

Comment: Are you aware of the snapshot feature, cause this is normally used for this type of test: http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/snapshot-testing.html#content

Comment: Yes, I know. I figure out. Thanks. Somebody help me close this question.